# Python stacktrace without sitepackages?

Tags: python-3.7

I was wondering if there is a way to get a **'simplified'** version of the exception **stacktrace**.
one that does not contain the trace of functions that are sourced in outside site-packages.

kind of like Justmycode. but for python with pycharm..

I have tried looking around but haven't found anything yet,
i'm aware that I can take the Stacktrace and filter out rows that are from outside sources,

but I really thought there would already be a solution for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible if you override a few methods in the [`traceback`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/traceback.py) module with a monkey patch. I've done similar modifications before back when they were all functions in Python 2.7. In Python 3.5+ they are all class methods now, however.

Comment: Thanks! but i'm looking for a site package that when toggled on - does this, so that my project won't have code in it handling these kinds of things. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [tbvaccine](https://github.com/skorokithakis/tbvaccine) Python package shows relevant lines highlighted, which is like a visual filter of irrelevant lines.

The package doesn't seem to be under active development btw.